Bluetooth GPS Device Pairs but Doesn't Connect on Raspberry Pi Ubuntu Server
I have a Trimble R1 GPS device, which doesn't specify support for Ubuntu, however there are drivers for Windows, and apps available for Android and iOS. I need to bind serial ports to the Bluetooth GPS device so I can read NMEA sentences. I'm using a Raspberry Pi. I already have a working script in place that can parse the binary data coming in from the serial port, so all I'm struggling with is getting the devices to connect and exchange the data.
When trying to use bluetoothctl, pair XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX seems to work fine, however the connect XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX command returns Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.NotAvailable br-connection-profile-unavailable
Checking btmon shows that some data looks to be exchanged, before the device requests to disconnect. It doesn't seem like there is a good indication of why this might be happening.
...
> HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5                                                                                  #33 [hci0] 9.312221
        Num handles: 1
        Handle: 12 Address: 0C:61:CF:24:53:D7 (Texas Instruments)
        Count: 1
        #31: len 24 (0 Kb/s)
        Latency: 235 msec (2-235 msec ~127 msec)
        Channel: 66 [PSM 1 mode Basic (0x00)] {chan 0}
        Channel Latency: 235 msec (3-235 msec ~119 msec)
< ACL Data TX: Handle 12 flags 0x00 dlen 12                                                                                            #34 [hci0] 11.586892
      L2CAP: Disconnection Request (0x06) ident 5 len 4
        Destination CID: 66
        Source CID: 64
> ACL Data RX: Handle 12 flags 0x02 dlen 12                                                                                            #35 [hci0] 11.592545
      L2CAP: Disconnection Response (0x07) ident 5 len 4
        Destination CID: 66
        Source CID: 64
> HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5                                                                                 #36 [hci0] 11.812223
        Num handles: 1
        Handle: 12 Address: 0C:61:CF:24:53:D7 (Texas Instruments)
        Count: 1
        #34: len 12 (0 Kb/s)
        Latency: 225 msec (2-235 msec ~176 msec)
< HCI Command: Disconnect (0x01|0x0006) plen 3                                                                                         #37 [hci0] 13.599716
        Handle: 12 Address: 0C:61:CF:24:53:D7 (Texas Instruments)
        Reason: Remote User Terminated Connection (0x13)
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4                                                                                              #38 [hci0] 13.600151
      Disconnect (0x01|0x0006) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
> HCI Event: Disconnect Complete (0x05) plen 4                                                                                         #39 [hci0] 13.697542
        Status: Success (0x00)
        Handle: 12 Address: 0C:61:CF:24:53:D7 (Texas Instruments)
        Reason: Connection Terminated By Local Host (0x16)
@ MGMT Event: Device Disconnected (0x000c) plen 8                                                                                 {0x0001} [hci0] 13.697592
        BR/EDR Address: 0C:61:CF:24:53:D7 (Texas Instruments)
        Reason: Connection terminated by local host (0x02)

I've also tried binding the rfcomm port directly to the mac address. The device has several different channels, and I've tried binding all of them to a different rfcomm port with no success.
sudo rfcomm bind rfcommx 0C:61:CF:24:53:D7 x
I checked the output with gpsd and cgps doesn't show any data transfer happening on any of the channels.
Here is the result from sdptool browse XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:
Browsing 0C:61:CF:24:53:D7 ...
Service Name: COM1
Service RecHandle: 0x10006
Service Class ID List:
  "Serial Port" (0x1101)
Protocol Descriptor List:
  "L2CAP" (0x0100)
  "RFCOMM" (0x0003)
    Channel: 1
Language Base Attr List:
  code_ISO639: 0x656e
  encoding:    0x6a
  base_offset: 0x100
Profile Descriptor List:
  "Serial Port" (0x1101)
    Version: 0x0100

Service Name: COM2
Service RecHandle: 0x10005
Service Class ID List:
  "Serial Port" (0x1101)
Protocol Descriptor List:
  "L2CAP" (0x0100)
  "RFCOMM" (0x0003)
    Channel: 2
Language Base Attr List:
  code_ISO639: 0x656e
  encoding:    0x6a
  base_offset: 0x100
Profile Descriptor List:
  "Serial Port" (0x1101)
    Version: 0x0100

Service Name: COM3
Service RecHandle: 0x10004
Service Class ID List:
  "Serial Port" (0x1101)
Protocol Descriptor List:
  "L2CAP" (0x0100)
  "RFCOMM" (0x0003)
    Channel: 3
Language Base Attr List:
  code_ISO639: 0x656e
  encoding:    0x6a
  base_offset: 0x100
Profile Descriptor List:
  "Serial Port" (0x1101)
    Version: 0x0100

Service Name: GNSS Server
Service RecHandle: 0x10008
Service Class ID List:
  "Serial Port" (0x1101)
  "" (0x1136)
Protocol Descriptor List:
  "L2CAP" (0x0100)
  "RFCOMM" (0x0003)
    Channel: 4
Language Base Attr List:
  code_ISO639: 0x656e
  encoding:    0x6a
  base_offset: 0x100
Profile Descriptor List:
  "" (0x1135)
    Version: 0x0100

Failed to connect to SDP server on 0C:61:CF:24:53:D7: Connection refused

I'm not sure if that last error is relevant to the connection here. When I'm using this device on a windows machine, I'm able to get the NMEA sentences from COM13. I'm not seeing that service name pop up here.
*Update: I'm using Ubuntu 24.04 LTS.

I think it is clear that the device does not support a file transfer as you are trying. You need the software that was designed to be used with it.

Please edit the question and add the version of Ubuntu that you are using.

I added the version 24.04 LTS. I don't need any additional software to read it on my Windows machine after the bluetooth is setup through the OS. The bluetooth emulates a serial port which then just gives a NMEA signal each second which I can parse. Screening the rfcomm port doesn't show any data transfer.

Maybe you need to start the gpsd?  Attached is an old script I used for a Delorm bluetooth gps, to use with viking maps:

#!/bin/bash
# Start a gps receiver with bluetooth output
# Then determine if the gps daemon is already running
xxx=`ps -eo pid,comm |grep [g]psd`
if [ -n "$xxx" ]; then 
  set `echo $xxx`
  pidgpsd=$1
fi

MYGPS=`grep "^[^#].*device.*;" /etc/bluetooth/rfcomm.conf |cut -f2 -d" "|cut -f1 -d";"`

#Determine if the rfcomm0 device has been created
if [ ! -e /dev/rfcomm0 ]; then
  # kill the old gpsd
  if [ -n "$pidgpsd" ]; then
    # for icon invocation, use gksudo
    pkexec kill $pidgpsd
    unset pidgpsd
  fi
  sdptool add --channel=1 OPUSH
  #gksudo rfcomm bind /dev/rfcomm0 00:0A:3A:2C:BC:44
  pkexec rfcomm bind /dev/rfcomm0 $MYGPS
  sleep 5
fi

# Start the new gpsd if necessary
if [ ! -n "$pidgpsd" ]; then
  #sudo gpsd -n -N -D2 /dev/rfcomm0
  pkexec -- gpsd -n -D2 /dev/rfcomm0
  echo "gpsd started"
  sleep 5
fi

# Create a ttyUSB0 link for broken viking
if [ ! -e /dev/ttyUSB0 ]; then
  sudo ln -s /dev/rfcomm0 /dev/ttyUSB0
fi

#/usr/local/bin/gpsdrive
#$HOME/work/gps/gpsdrive-2.11/build/src/gpsdrive
sudo viking


As I read it the connection works but the OP s attempt to pull the data fails.

The Bluetooth connection itself is failing. Screening the rfcomm port gives no data exchange
